# Using Mysql xdevapi

Tags: mysql, typescript, mysql-x-devapi

I am trying to work with Mysql as a document store using xdevapi, but it is written in JavaScript and I am using TypeScript,so I found mysqlx a type definition for xdevapi and I don't know if it is a good one. Is there any better alternative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really say if it's good or not, but the fact is that the original [`@mysql/xdevapi`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@mysql/xdevapi) package does not include any TypeScript definitions.

You can track the following enhancement request for adding TypeScript support and signal your own interest in it.

https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=103438

Disclaimer: I'm the lead developer of the MySQL X DevAPI Connector for Node.js

Comment: I was waiting for you to answer . It would be great if they privide TypeScript support for it

Comment: FYI, TypeScript definitions are available since v8.0.30.